# What is a proper pattern to serve images from cluster

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, kubernetes, ceph

I have a problem with scaling an app, I want to serve static images from my server, but I can not find any useful information on how to do this. I use Kubernetes, Nginx and my services are running on express.js. I have 2 ideas but I would like to ask you before I will start implementing one of them.

So my first idea is to create global storage using gluster or cephfs but I have never worked with this technology and it seems to be tough to set up the cluster.

The second idea is to save the URL as machine_ip/path but I am not sure if exposing machine IP and path like that, does not break some security rules. Here is a question is it possible to generate a URL for the file to hide path and ip?

Maybe you have another idea or tips? I know I can use s3 but in my case, there are a lot of IOPS I am kind of worried about the price.

Comment: Did you think about a CDN? Wouldn't it solve your problem?

Comment: In first sentence you wrote - "I have a problem with scaling an app" - what is the exact issue?

Comment: I am fighting with cephfs right now, but I have 0 experience as a sysadmin or devops so maintaining cephfs cluster in long term will be really exhausting. Eventually, I will rebuild the service and go for s3. But still, I am looking for different solutions.